# How to display image using JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I'm using the following tag to display image but this tag is not displaying any image why ?

```
<img src="H:\IVS-FEB 2016\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\IVS\uploads\share1.png">
```

I stored image in

> H:\IVS-FEB 2016.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\IVS\uploads\share1.png

and my working directory of eclipse is

> H:\IVS-FEB 2016

Comment: Because a web browser loads images from the web server using HTTP. It doesn't load images from the file system. Your code should most probably be `src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/uploads/share1.png"`.

Comment: I added code suggested by you but is still not displaying image, can you please explain what ${pageContext.request.contextPath} do here...